# JIRA Creation: TypeError: Object of type Timestamp is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, jira

So this code worked before and now I am getting a JSON error. I googled the fixes with datetime and json.dump but I can't figure my way out of this. I'm not sure how to implement into this code when there isn't a direct date variable.

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('JIRA.xlsx', header=0, index=False).dropna(how='all')

options = {'server': 'https://act.genpt.net'}

jira_user = input('User Name: ')
jira_password = input('Password: ')

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    summary = row[2]
    description = 'Research and assign attributes'
    owner = row[3]
    dueDate = row[4]

    issue_dict = {
        'project': 11208,
        'issuetype': {'name': 'Task'},
        'summary': summary,
        'priority': {'id': '7'},
        'description': description,
        'environment': 'PROD',
        'components': 'Item Type Clean Up',
        'customfield_10108': owner,
        'duedate': dueDate
        }

    new = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.datetime` objects, like `datetime.datetime` objects, are not `json` serializable and will cause these errors. The best way to get around this would be to string-format your datetime, because strings are hashable:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    summary = row[2]
    description = 'Research and assign attributes'
    owner = row[3]
    dueDate = row[4]

    issue_dict = {
        'project': 11208,
        'issuetype': {'name': 'Task'},
        'summary': summary,
        'priority': {'id': '7'},
        'description': description,
        'environment': 'PROD',
        'components': 'Item Type Clean Up',
        'customfield_10108': owner,
        # You will have to know the format of the datetime and
        # input that as the argument
        'duedate': dueDate.strftime('<date_format_here>')
        }
```

The docs for which are located [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)